# HostOutOfMemory alerts are firing in slack channel in prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana

alert: HostOutOfMemory
expr: node_memory_MemAvailable_bytes
/ node_memory_MemTotal_bytes * 100 < 10
for: 2m
labels:
severity: critical
annotations:
summary: Host only has 10% memory left (instance {{ $labels.instance }}). Pod eviction
will be triggered.

Comment: Labels
alertname = HostOutOfMemory
app = prometheus
app_kubernetes_io_instance = prometheus--staging
chart = prometheus-13.3.2
component = node-exporter
heritage = Helm
instance = 10.1.13.160:9100
job = kubernetes-service-endpoints
kubernetes_name = prometheus-node-exporter
kubernetes_namespace = metrics
kubernetes_node = ip-10-1-13-160.us-west-2.compute.internal
release = prometheus
severity = critical
Annotations
summary = Host only has 10% memory left (instance 10.1.13.160:9100). Pod eviction will be triggered.

Comment: These are the alerts i am getting fired in slack channel please tell me solution for this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your worker node are running out of memory. To mitigate this you could either:

1. Scale up your cluster, e.g. add additional worker nodes.
2. Reduce memory consumption by your current workloads, e.g. scale down deployment or reconfigure or introduce [resource limits](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/).

Comment: Thank you i will try